# DataGrid for joined tables is not editable

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I've joined two tables using LINQ that their relations was mapped in EF but now the data shown in datagrid is not editable how I can make this possible?

My join expression :

```
CMIS_Entities context = new CMIS_Entities();
var query = context.PI_Line.Join(context.PI_Sheet, c => c.idL, x => x.idL, (c, x) => new
{

    Sheet=x.Sh1.ToString() + "/" + c.TotalSheet.ToString(),
    Sh1=x.Sh1,
    idS=x.idS,
    idL=c.idL,
    IsoLine=x.Line3,
    SheetValidity=x.SheetValidity,
    Pos=c.Pos,
    Zone=c.Zone,
    Line=c.Line,
    WellHead=c.WellHead,
    Validity=c.RevValid
}).ToList();

Line_Grid.ItemsSource = query;
```

Answer (score 0):

DataGrid creates columns for each property of items in ItemsSource. Columns are editable if  property has a `public` setter. In this case ItemsSource consists of anonymous objects, which are immutable, therefore DataGrid is readonly

Create a named class with required properties, and tranform query results into instances of that class:

```
public class DataItem 
{
   public string Sheet { get; set; }
   ...
   public bool Validity { get; set; }
}

CMIS_Entities context = new CMIS_Entities();
var results = context.PI_Line.Join(context.PI_Sheet, c => c.idL, x => x.idL, (c, x) => new DataItem
{

    Sheet=x.Sh1.ToString() + "/" + c.TotalSheet.ToString(),
    Sh1=x.Sh1,
    idS=x.idS,
    idL=c.idL,
    IsoLine=x.Line3,
    SheetValidity=x.SheetValidity,
    Pos=c.Pos,
    Zone=c.Zone,
    Line=c.Line,
    WellHead=c.WellHead,
    Validity=c.RevValid
}).ToList();

Line_Grid.ItemsSource = results;
```